# Laravel 4 - unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 32 bytes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I install Laravel 4, I receive this error:

```
ErrorException
unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 32 bytes

C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\laravel\bootstrap\compiled.php
return unserialize($this->stripPadding($this->mcryptDecrypt($value, $iv)));
```

If I modify return like this:

```
return unserialize(base64_decode($this->stripPadding($this->mcryptDecrypt($value, $iv))));
```

Then the error goes away. But of course every time I run composer update this change will be undone.

What could be the reason of this problem?

I appreciate any help.

**Update:** This only happens when I use Auth::check().

**Update 2:** Now it only works with base64_decode() removed. It's like if the xampp installation has become self-aware. Jesus!

Comment: I'd say it is but make sure the `mcrypt` module is loaded. Check your `phpinfo()` and check `php -m` from the command line.

Comment: If I run `php --ri mcrypt` everything is fine. All the problems I had in the last days with Laravel 4 seems to be related to mcrypt, I guess it's time to a clean install of xampp.

Comment: Mr. Lewis, if it only happens with Auth::check(), then I suppose all comes down to `return 'login_'.md5(get_class($this));` in **Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php** at line 544. If that is the case, this is definitely a mcrypt problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Refer to this issue: [laravel/framework#1526](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1526#issuecomment-18912773)

A change in the encryption mechanism is the cause. My solution was to empty out the `sessions` and `views` that were cached in the `storage` folder, then run `php artisan key:generate` and relaunch the server. I'm not sure which part of the process fixed the issue, but I haven't seen it since.

Comment: Ok, I did a fresh install to resolve it, I can't test your suggestion, but makes a lot of sense what you say. Thank you for pointing the issue at github, nobody could help me when it first came out and I was just about to disintegrate my current xampp installation.

Comment: This problem occured after my machine suffered a blue-screen crash. Not sure what happened exactly, but following your instructions has got my app working again. Thank you! +1

Comment: at last "php artisan key:generate" command fix my problem. thanks. :)

Comment: I only emptied the sessions and views folders in storage, and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The command > php artisan cache:clear fixed the problem for me.
I did not have to restart the server

Comment: Didn't work for me, but clearing out the folders as @Dwight suggested worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what you're doing that causes this error? You shouldn't be modifying the core - because as you said, updates will overwrite it.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this only happens when I use Auth::check().

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a news Key, use the following command:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

After that test again to run the Laravel Application

```
php artisan serve
```