# Laravel unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 355 bytes

Tags: php, laravel-4

Everything was going correct. Then there was a power failure while I was editing my laravel code(view). After 2 hours I opened it again and got this exception:

unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 355 bytes

[image]

Comment: Looks like your serialized data is corrupt. Clear your session data and try again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 - unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 32 bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863156/laravel-4-unserialize-error-at-offset-0-of-32-bytes)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for Firefox browser.

step1 - Right click on the browser page and click on 'View Page Info'

(For Chrome ,click on the link 'show cookies and the site data' and remove all the cookies . and check if it is solved.)

step2 - click on the 'Security' tab

step3 - click on the 'View Cookies' button

step4 - click on the 'remove all' button  then close it

problem solved.

still if you are getting the error.
Then click on the 'View Saved Password' and clear them also.

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear all the cookies, worked for me for a laravel app.

For Chrome

1. Open Inspect
2. Then Application
3. Select Cookies
4. Click 'Clear All Cookies'
5. Then delete cache folder in storage\framework\ in your laravel project directory
6. Done